# Doctrine 2 ORM creates classes with hateful CamelCase

Tags: doctrine-orm, getter-setter, camelcasing

I created yaml configuration for Doctrine. When I'm trying `doctrine orm:generate-entities`, it creates php files with getters and setters in camel case. So, `is_public` field transforms into `setIsPublic` and `getIsPublic` methods. It's owful. How can I get `set_is_public` and `get_is_public`? I can manually edit generated php files, but I don't know what will happen when I change the schema.

Comment: I have to agree that yours is an uncommon opinion of method naming.  Considering your platform (PHP) itself uses camelCased method names for built-in objects, you're definitely going against the grain.  However, it's an interesting question, so I've upvoted it (undoing some other hateful downvote)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [choose a naming strategy](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/namingstrategy.html) that Doctrine will use to generate the items using:

> Using a naming strategy you can provide rules for automatically
> generating database identifiers, columns and tables names when the
> table/column name is not given. This feature helps reduce the
> verbosity of the mapping document, eliminating repetitive noise (eg:
> TABLE_).

For your specific case, I think you're looking at something like:

```
$namingStrategy = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy(CASE_LOWER);
$configuration()->setNamingStrategy($namingStrategy);
```

The linked topic goes on to show you how you can write your own custom naming strategy.

If you're using Symfony, it's [even easier](http://elnur.pro/how-to-enable-the-underscore-naming-strategy-for-doctrine-orm-in-symfony/) (like most things are with Symfony, but that's just my opinion) via `config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
```

Comment: Maybe you should add *… using underscores will require an additional `name="user_id"` parameter in your `@ORM\Column annotation`*

Comment: My understanding is that telling Doctrine to use a specific naming strategy would remove the need to explicitly make the variable to column name relations yourself. Doctrine knows what to do now that you've told it this.

Comment: I think that it would be interesting to provide the alternative `@ORM\Column` annotation that can be used only when needed, without modifying the global naming strategy.

Answer (score 3):

[Symfony's coding standards](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html#naming-conventions) encourage Symfony users to use **camelCase**:

> #### Naming Conventions
>
> Use camelCase, not underscores, for variable,
>   function and method names, arguments

Comment: This isn't a Doctrine coding standard rule - it's Symfony's. Doctrine doesn't seem to enforce a specific case for variable names, but, given that it's ultimately PHP, camel case is a good bet. Note that using camel case when your table column names are using underscores will require an additional `name="user_id"` parameter in your `@ORM\Column` annotation.

Comment: @aalaap Thanks, I don't know why I wrote that it was a Doctrine whereas I quoted and linked the Symfony documentation. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @aalaap Feel free to add your answer with the same content as your comment. My answer is off-topic.

Comment: I did. Too bad the OP will probably never see this.

Answer (score 0):

Personal advice - do not generate entities by doctrine orm:generate-entities. 
Use plain PHP to create class. Why? 
Orm uses **reflection** on privates to communicate with database. You dont need to generate setters and getters. I recomend You to use design patterns such as factory or constructor to achive Your goal. Decorators also should work fine.

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function __construct(int $id, string $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

$camelCase is not only Symfony's recomendation for code standard. It's based on PSR2. I highly recomend using PSR2, code gets clean and standarized. 
Standard ORM naming strategy is **$camelCase** private var to **snake_case** column name. If you want to change it otherwise, consider: [other naming stategies](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/namingstrategy.html)